# Freemarker "if" condition for null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am checking the value of a an attribute in a freemarker which is set in the Spring controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doAction(@RequestParam(name = EMAIL, required = false) String email,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

       //Some actions
      ...
      ...
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("token", "token");

        return AUTH_OAUTH_PW_PATH + VERIFY_PATH;

    }

The freemarker check is like: 
The html component should appear only if the value of the attribute "token" is not found.

<#if !(token?has_content)>
           <br></br>   
        <div id="divId">
        <p><a href="link" id="id1">Hello</a></p>
        </div>
</#if>
```

Even if the value is not set for the token, the ftl hyperlink is visible.

Answer (score 2):

?? test operator checks if object is not null

Try with following:

```
<#if token??>
<#else
        <br></br>   
        <div id="divId">
        <p><a href="link" id="id1">Hello</a></p>
        </div>
</#if>
```

Comment: OP said that it should appear if `token` is *not* found, so that's `!token??` then. (However, `!token?has_content` should be `true` for `null` as well, even if it's more verbose. Note sure why that doesn't work for them.)

Comment: I have tried this.But, it completely makes the html disappearing.